# SQL PIVOT replacement in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have two tables:

- STUDENTS
- APPLICATION

A student can apply to 1-3 programs.

Student_ID is a column on Application.

**Table structure
APPLICATION**

```
ID  | Student_ID   | Program__c
1   |     65432    |  ComputerScience
2   |     65432    |  Math
3   |     65432    |  Cinema
4   |     65431    |  Theatre
5   |     65431    |  Cinema
```

etc...
The end goal is to get to this:

1 student per row, with all their application programs

**Expected results**

```
Student_ID  | Program1        |  Program2 | Program3
65432       | ComputerScience |  Math     | Cinema
65431       | Theatre         |  Cinema   |
```

**Question:**
- How do I achieve this with an SQL query?

I have tried the following Pivot, but getting error on syntax, not sure if pivot is supported,
although it's not on the list of exclusions in the official doc.

```
select Student_ID, [1] as value_1, [2] as value_2, [3] as value_3
from
(
  select Student_ID, Program__c,
    row_number() over(partition by Program__c order by Program__c) rnk
  from Application__c_Salesforce
) d
pivot
(
  max(Program__c)
  for rnk in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

Comment: How are you going to use this pivoted data?  If it's for use in an email, I wouldn't bother trying to pivot it.  It's much easier to script in the email.

Comment: Thank you Adam. Yes, it's in an email,
need to refer to all 3 programs that match the same student in the same email. All 3 programs are stored in the same Synchoronized DE - Application__c_Salesforce. Is there away to loop through matching results? how? (Also a link to documentation would be very appreciated!)  Thanks again @AdamSpriggs !

Comment: Oh and another challenge @AdamSpriggs is that Program__c is actually the Id for a Salesforce Account object in Marketing Cloud - the example above is simplified. (Program__c is a lookup to Account in Salesforce). So I'd have to eventually dig out the real name of the program (text field on Account Object) to show in the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to pivot the data in a Query Activity, you could do something like this in your email scripting.

(This is assuming the you'd be sending to a sendable Data Extension of Application records.)

```
%%[

var @ApplicationRows, @ApplicationRow, @ApplicationRowCount, @Application_ID, @i, @debug
set @debug = 1

set @Application_ID = AttributeValue("Application_ID") /* value DE column in send context */
set @ApplicationRows = LookupRows("APPLICATION","ID", @Application_ID)
set @ApplicationRowCount = rowcount(@ApplicationRows)

if @debug == 1 then 
    output(concat("Application_ID: ", @Application_ID))
endif 

if @ApplicationRowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @ApplicationRowCount do

    var @Student_ID, @Program__c, @rank
    set @ApplicationRow = row(@ApplicationRows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @Program__c = field(@ApplicationRow,"Program__c")
    set @Student_ID = field(@ApplicationRow,"Student_ID")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Student_ID: %%=v(@Student_ID)=%%, Program__c: %%=v(@Program__c)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No Application rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Reference**

- [lookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows)

Comment: Hi Adam - what’s the purpose of the debug variable in this script?

Comment: For debug output. I like to verify values before conditionals, especially ones from the send context.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, this is g-r-e-a-t !
Application, of course, is not a sendable DE - STUDENTS is.  I'd have to create a sendable DE with a simple SQL join between the two, no prob!   For the second part - Program__c is actually the ID of Account__c_Salesforce. Is there a way, in the email scripting, to get the real ProgramName__c field from Account based on the id (Program__c)? (i.e. query Account object in scripting) - Or would you recommend a double-join when I create the Sendable DE with Students & Application so to add Students join Application join Account?

Comment: I'd prep as much of the 1:1 data as you can with the Query Activity and then leverage AMPscript lookups for the 1:N data.

Answer (score 0):

old ticket, but a solution, if only 3 programs can taken.

## SQL

```
select
    student_ID,
    max(case when rn=1 then program__c else '' end) as program1,
    max(case when rn=2 then program__c else '' end) as program2,
    max(case when rn=3 then program__c else '' end) as program3
from (    
    select
    student_ID,
    program__c,
    row_number() over (partition by student_id order by program__c) as rn
    from APPLICATION
) t0
group by student_ID
```

## Result

```
student_id  program1    program2        program3
65431       Cinema      Theatre 
65432       Cinema      ComputerScience Math
```